# Multiple props in Ramda lens

Tags: ramda.js

Is there a way to apply transforms to multiple keys of an object in Ramda? I am aware this is achievable by R.evolve, but I am interested in knowing if this can be achieved by some modification of lenses.
E.g.:

```
const data = {
  a: "100",
  b: "non_numeric_string",
  c: "0.5"
}

const numerize = x => +x

const mapping = {
  a: numerize,
  c: numerize
}

magicFunction(mapping, data) 

output:
{
  a: 100,
  b: "non_numeric_string",
  c: 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a lens is to focus on one part of a data structure.  While it is not hard to write something using `lensProp` to achieve this, I'm don't think it's either very satisfying or a particularly appropriate use of lenses.  Here's one Ramda solution:

```js
const magicFunction = (mapping, data) =>
  reduce 
    ( (o, [k, fn]) => over (lensProp(k), fn, o) 
    , data
    , toPairs (mapping)
    )

const numerize = x => Number (x)

const mapping = {
  a: numerize,
  c: numerize
}

const data = {a: "100", b: "non_numeric_string", c: "0.5"}

console .log (
  magicFunction (mapping, data)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const { lensProp, over, reduce, toPairs } = R               </script>
```

But note that a plain ES6 function does the job just as simply, without using lenses:

```js
const magicFunction = (mapping, data) =>
  Object.entries (mapping). reduce 
    ( (o, [k, fn]) => ({...o, [k]: fn (o [k]) }) 
    , data
    )
```

Lenses simply don't gain you much here.